Change embedded field names on symfony to avoid Unrecognized field: App\Domain\Entity\User::$email issue
I have this entity
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Entity;

use App\Domain\ValueObject\Email;
use App\Domain\ValueObject\Name;
use App\Domain\ValueObject\Password;
use App\Domain\ValueObject\Surname;
use Ramsey\Uuid\UuidInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private UuidInterface $id,
        private Name $name,
        private Surname $surname,
        private Email $email,
        private Password $password,
        private array $roles = []
    ) {}

    public function getId(): UuidInterface
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(UuidInterface $id): void
    {
        $this->$id = $id;
    }

    public function getName(): Name
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(Name $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getSurname(): Surname
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(Surname $surname): void
    {
        $this->surname = $surname; 
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email->value();
    }

    public function setEmail(String $email): void
    {
        $this->$email = new Email($email);
    }

    public function getVOEmail(): Email
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setVOEmail(Email $email): void
    {
        $this->$email = $email;
    }

    public function getVOPassword(): Password
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setVOPassword(Password $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password->value();
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the roles granted to the user.
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        // Garantizar que cada usuario tenga al menos el rol ROLE_USER
        if (empty($this->roles)) {
            $this->roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }

        return array_unique($this->roles);
    }

    /**
     * Set the roles for the user.
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): static
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get the user identifier (e.g., email).
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return $this->email->value(); // O cualquier otro identificador único
    }

    /**
     * Erase any sensitive information.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // Si hay información sensible que deseas eliminar, hazlo aquí.
        // Por ejemplo, si usaste una contraseña sin encriptar durante la autenticación:
        // $this->plainPassword = null; // O cualquier otro campo temporal.
    }
}

mapped this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doctrine/doctrine2/main/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <!-- Definición de la entidad -->
    <entity name="App\Domain\Entity\User" table="`user`" repository-class="App\Infrastructure\Service\UserRepository">
        
        <!-- Identificador (ID) -->
        <id name="id" type="uuid" column="id">
            <generator strategy="NONE"/> <!-- Usamos un UUID generado manualmente -->
        </id>

        <!-- Definición de los campos -->
        <embedded name="email" class="App\Domain\ValueObject\Email" use-column-prefix="false"/>
        <embedded name="name" class="App\Domain\ValueObject\Name" use-column-prefix="false"/>
        <embedded name="surname" class="App\Domain\ValueObject\Surname" use-column-prefix="false"/>
        <embedded name="password" class="App\Domain\ValueObject\Password" use-column-prefix="false"/>
        
        <!-- Definición de la columna JSON para los roles -->
        <field name="roles" type="json" column="roles"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

and the embeddable mapping
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      https://raw.githubusercontent.com/doctrine/doctrine2/main/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <!-- Definición del objeto embebido -->
    <embeddable name="App\Domain\ValueObject\Email">
        <!-- Campo de la clase Email -->
        <field name="value" column="email" type="string" length="255" nullable="false"/>
    </embeddable>
</doctrine-mapping>

Email is a Value Object(as the rest on attributes) the I used an embeddeded classes for the attributes ,I worked for store the users on the database but not for login using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle the problem is that when I try to login an user I get this error Unrecognized field: App\Domain\Entity\User::$email
Debugging I found that this code
$this->class->fieldMappings[$field]

doesn't retuen the field names as email,name,surname... it returns email.value , name.value... at the class as email value is contained on a variable called $value
<?php

namespace App\Domain\ValueObject;

    class Email
    {
        public function __construct(private string $value)
        {}
    
        public function value(): string
        {
            return $this->value;
        }
    }

I don't know how to make to get name instead of name.value when $this->class->fieldMappings[$field] is called the name is already set on the xml configuration file

It's pretty non-standard way to save such data as user name and email as VOs. You will benefit in the long term if you just drop this idea and refactor your entity to save this kind of data as string (you always can create separate methods to set and get those values as VOs).
If LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle is limited to use ORM mapping to get those properties, and you can not override this behavior, I don't see a solution, unfortunately. As the last resort you could override this part of code in the bundle itself (by overriding the service using symfony DI, if possible), but I wouldn't recommend this either, since it may lead to even worse cases and unpredictable cases in the future (not mentioning the problems after upgrading the package).
One last thing, if there's a way to somehow give LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle a property path instead of the mapped fields, you could probably create a separate getters (e.g. getEmailValue, getNameValue), and make the bundle to use emailValue and nameValue properties instead. But, again, this is most likely not possible to do out of the box with this bundle.
